# "Pointer to reference" error in Visual Studio is not displayed by filename where it occurs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

Some errors in Visual Studio are not displayed by the filename of the source code where they are created, which makes them difficult to find and debug.

In this particular example, I have the error pointing to `#include <vector>` header, but I cannot trace it to the source file where the actual code error is. `Error    C2528   'data': pointer to reference is illegal c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector   1246`

If this was a runtime error, I would be able to use the Call Stack to see where in the code the runtime crash occurred.

Is there a similar way to find this error with compiler errors? Or am I stuck looking through source code to see where the error can potentially be manually?

Just for information, this is not a post asking how to fix this particular error, but a post asking how to find the source file where the errors occur quickly. Therefore I am not posting any source code, the error provided here is an example of the type of error that would cause the confusing compiler messages,

Comment: Find where you use `data` and not `data()`. It also helps to comment out a large amount of code, see if the error is in the other half, if it is keep going until the last thing you've commented out contains the problem.

Comment: You might be using something like `name_of_vector.data` instead of `name_of_vector.data()` to get the address of the start of the vector's data. Sometimes this blows up in the header file depending on how it's used in your source.

Comment: The error message should normally contain more lines either above or below the one you're looking at that show which line in your own code triggers the error, sort of similar to a stack trace (error in file included from here included from there included from your code, that sort of thing). My wild guess is that you're using `vector<someclass&>` instead of `vector<someclass>`. If the error message does not contain more lines, could you provide a minimal example that would allow us to replicate the behavior?

Comment: this particular error was caused by having an st::vector of references. Which a compiler should have been easily able to track to the file the vector was created in. But instead it generated 100 errors pointing to the `vector.h` file. Which is why I'm so confused about the way some of these errors are displayed

Comment: Look in the Output tab and select 'Build' from the dropdown.  You should see a 'traceback' of your error(s) there.

Comment: Thanks, that seems as the most useful answer, can you please post as an answer?

Comment: Output  Tab is almost always more useful than the Error List. Cuts and pastes into Stack Overflow editor windows nicely, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Output tab and select 'Build' from the dropdown. You should see a 'traceback' of your error(s) there.  As you have observed, the Error List tab just displays the line provoking the error.